# Error deleting an array while porting code from Windows to Linux

Tags: c++, linux, porting

I'm trying to port a library, which correctly works in Windows, to Linux.

In these lines of code I get an error:

```
long* permutation = new long[result->getGeneListCount()];
for(long i=0; i<result->getGeneListCount(); i++) 
        permutation[i]=i;
Util::ArrayUtil::DurstenfeldArrayPermutation<long>(permutation, result->getGeneListCount()); 

//result->PerformGenePermutation(permutation);
std::cout << "Just skipped the permutation" << std::endl;

delete[] permutation;
```

The error seems, to me, to occur during the deletion. I know that, since I have commented the `PerformGenePermutation()`, I could simply comment also the other lines, but similar problem could appear again in the other code, so I would like to understand the error.

The error-output which I get is:

```
*** glibc detected *** /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x09f287f8 ***
```

Can anyone help me, please?

Please, ask me if you need further details.

Comment: Is it possible `result->getGeneListCount()` retuns `0`?

Comment: Doesn't `permutation` pointer change over the call to `DurstenfeldArrayPermutation`? Could you verify that by printing the pointer value (`printf("%p\n", permutation);`) before and after the call? Does `DurstenfeldArrayPermutation` free the pointer by itself?

Comment: Does `DurstenfeldArrayPermutation` take its first parameter by reference? If so, it may attempt to reallocate it, which may be fine on some platforms (where `malloc` and `new[]` user the same underlying allocator) but not on others.

Comment: @ahenderson: I tried, it doesn't return 0!

Comment: @ulidtko : I checked, but the value of permutation doesn't change after the function.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, I'm going to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given code & info is not sufficient to nail down the cause of the problem, but you can do the following:

replace the code

```
long* permutation = new long[result->getGeneListCount()];
for(long i=0; i<result->getGeneListCount(); i++) 
        permutation[i]=i;
Util::ArrayUtil::DurstenfeldArrayPermutation<long>(permutation, result->getGeneListCount()); 

//result->PerformGenePermutation(permutation);
std::cout << "Just skipped the permutation" << std::endl;

delete[] permutation;
```

with

```
std::vector<long> permutation( result->getGeneListCount() );
for(long i=0; i<long(permutation.size()); i++) 
        permutation[i]=i;
Util::ArrayUtil::DurstenfeldArrayPermutation<long>(&permutation.at( 0 ), permutation.size()); 

//result->PerformGenePermutation(permutation);
std::cout << "Just skipped the permutation" << std::endl;

//delete[] permutation;
```

Note that the `delete` is removed since `std::vector` does that automatically for you.

If this now throws an exception from range error from `std::vector::at`, well then you know that the size is probably zero. Anyway you can now very simply check that in your debugger. And more importantly, if it does *not* throw an exception, then you know that all's well and good with this code (because `std::vector` is reliable), so the problem is then elsewhere.

Unfortunately this was too long to post as a comment, but it's not really an *answer*. This is a problem with SO. Since it's designed for pure answers it doesn't support general *help*.

Comment: Well, it worked. No exceptions have been thrown. For now it's enough for me :)